# Chrome specific issue with z-index and flash

Tags: flash, google-chrome, z-index

I'm trying to get an absolutely positioned DIV to display in front of a Flash object; I can get this to work in every browser except Chrome.

There are a couple of similar questions on here, but nothing pertaining to a problem with Chrome specifically. I've tried several of the suggested solutions, such as setting the 'wmode' param to 'transparent', and setting z-indexes for both the flash object and the div, but nothing seems to work.

To see this in action:

[www.mapcrunch.com](http://www.mapcrunch.com)

There is some green text: "Click here to begin", which should appear in front of the Street View panorama. In Chrome, you can see that the DIV appears in the correct position, but is then obliterated by the Flash object.

This issue is driving me nuts, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, have you looked at the other 'wmode' available? I think there's a "normal" value too, which if I recall correctly will set your Flash object flat on a layer (like it should :P) in its current container.

So just make sure its within it's own DIV tag too and has a z-index setup as well.

HTML Flash embedding ain't really something I do on a daily basis (even less tested in Chrome) but hopefully this will shed some light.

Comment: There are three wmods - window (default), opaque and transparent. Last two makes the flash object part of normal display order in document, so with these z-index works normally.

Comment: ah yes... opaque I was thinking, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried both opaque and transparent (although, I can only set these via JavaScript after the Flash object has loaded - perhaps this is too late?)

Comment: Hmm it may be too late once it's loaded (just a guess though)

Comment: I had the same issue with Chrome. Setting wmode to opaque before the content loads fixes it.

Comment: I have the same issue with with Chrome, but only after upgrading to version 7+. In Chrome 6 it seemed to work fine without any wmode settings at all. For example this page http://www.cooper.com/journal/2010/10/making_it_suck.html used to show topnav over flash content...